# Calling a medium version of image in Wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails, pagespeed, image-size

Currently got this code in a 'recent posts' section on the homepage of a Wordpress site but this is calling the full size version of the image:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img style="float:left; margin:0px 10px 20px 0px; height:100px;" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
```

What I want to do is to call the medium sized images as this would make the page loading time much better than serving a potential 1000px+ image and scaling down to 10% of it's size wasting page speed.

Comment: If you're referring to the post thumbnail itself, you can use `the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );`

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get the right image. It returns an array:

- [0] => url
- [1] => width
- [2] => height
- [3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.

So try this:

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' )[0];
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me by showing how this code would look inside the code I provided in my original question (sorry I'm not a coder!)

Comment: `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img style="float:left; margin:0px 10px 20px 0px; height:100px;" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' )[0] ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>`

Comment: Then try this: `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img style="float:left; margin:0px 10px 20px 0px; height:100px;" src="<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' ); echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>`

Comment: It gives broken images.

Comment: Is the website online? Then I can check for errors. Otherwise could you please give the file you're changing to make it easier for me.

Comment: http://www.searleandco.ltd.uk - I can send you the files - easiest way to do that?

Comment: Do you want the whole theme or just the page this code is on.

Comment: I only want just that page

Comment: I changed the code in your code share, so you can copy the whole file. The change i made is this, it's another implementation with the same result: `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('style' => 'float:left; margin:0px 10px 20px 0px; height:100px;', 'alt' => get_the_title(), 'title' => get_the_title())); ?></a>`

Comment: That returns a space with no images. In the code it shows links to each post but no code at all to call the image.

Comment: Where is the image saved? Is it the featured image or is there some other place the image is stored? `the_post_thumbnail()` gets the featured image only...

Comment: stored in uploads. The image is called in the post in a custom field called "image" - it's a very old theme!

Comment: Okay that's why nothing worked... Here's the new code: `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img style="float:left; margin:0px 10px 20px 0px; height:100px;" src="<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true), 'medium' ); echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>` If this is not working, the it's probably not storing the image ID but the whole image object in the database. Then i need to change the code (again).

Comment: This produces a broken image and HTML code:

    <a href="http://www.searleandco.ltd.uk/aquamarine-and-pearl-brooch/"><img style="float:left; margin:0px 10px 20px 0px; height:100px;" src="" alt="Aquamarine and Pearl Brooch"></a>

So it doesn't pick up the image src.

Comment: Maybe it's easier if I could use team viewer to make it work on your computer. Could you please contact me privately so we can discuss?